# Can I inject javascript into a page via image?

Tags: javascript, image

Like so.
Can I inject javascript into image urls, like this?

```
<img src="javascript:alert("haha! you are hacked!">
```

Comment: *Everything that is rendered successfully in the client's browser. also what is in the alert function is not correctly enclosed

Comment: The closest thing (apart from the syntax error) you could do is to enter a .svg with javascript code, and use some social engineering to make the user open it in a new tab/window. E.g. by writing the text 'Right-click and open this in a new tab!' on the image. Curiosity killed the cat.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no.

The value of the img element's `src` attribute must resolve to an image content type. For example, http: and https: URIs resolve to whatever the value of the `Content-Type` response header is when the resource is fetched, and data: URIs resolve to the content type that is specified in the URI itself (and yes, you can use them in image tags).

I'm not actually sure whether Javascript URIs meaningfully resolve to any content type, but they sure don't resolve to an image. Therefore, the browser doesn't treat them as valid attribute values in that context, and won't attempt to execute them. In general, the only context where a javascript: URI is legal is anywhere it would be used for a window's location. This doesn't have to be a top-level window - iframes can use javascript: URIs in their src attribute - but it won't work for things like image sources, CSS sources, or even JS sources.